# How to find system log entry from right after login (Big Sur stalls for specific user)

Tags: big-sur, login, console

I run macOS Big Sur 11.6 on an iMac i9 from 2019. If I login after shutdown or restart as a specific user, the Finder beachballs and does not respond to anything besides moving a window for about two to three minutes. After that, the user's remaining startup items load (but take a lot of time also). After five minutes or so, everything is fine. The other user on the Mac (also an admin user) does not give me this problem.

I'd like to search the system logs via Console for problems appearing right after the user is logged in and the desktop appeared. The system uses FileVault, so the boot process continues after entering the login credentials. Everything seems to be normal until the desktop appears.

What shall I look for to find the right spot in the log?